# Unable to set few hibernate properties in Quarkus

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

I am trying to set this property (`hibernate.id.generator.stored_last_used`) in application.properties of a quarkus application. But quarkus is ignoring stating that it a `Unrecognized configuration key`.

How to set few hibernate properties which are not recognized by `quarkus-hibernate-orm` extension?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the persistence.xml.

In this [Quarkus Hibernate ORM guide - Setting up and configuring Hibernate ORM with a persistence.xml](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#persistence-xml) is written:

> Alternatively, you can use a META-INF/persistence.xml to set up Hibernate ORM. This is useful for:

> when you have relatively complex settings requiring the full flexibility of the configuration

Comment: Please note [[
If you have a persistence.xml, then you cannot use the quarkus.hibernate-orm.* properties and only persistence units defined in persistence.xml will be taken into account.]] 

Keep that in mind.

Comment: Yes, you're right @Susan Mustafa. I believe the persistence.xml must be used only as a last option.